# How to solve page header of crystal report won't export on excel

Tags: crystal-reports

I have suppressed page header in last page of crystal report using formula. It works fine while printing the report. But when i tried to export it as MS Excel 97-2000(Data only), the page header won't export(displayed) to excel.

Comment: if i was to guess i would say that it classes the exported excel sheet as a single page- hence the first page is the only page and in fact the last page- hence suppressed

Comment: yes, that is the problem. How to overcome this?

Comment: you could try making the suppression formula more explicit. instead of just checking if it's the last page, also check if it's the first page.

Comment: great- have posted as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try making the suppression formula more explicit. instead of just checking if it's the last page, also check if it's the first page.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you are trying to export it as `MS Excel 97-2000(Data only)`.

Instead, try exporting it as `MS Excel 97-2000`.

Comment: This way i can solve the problem. But i need to export it as Data only format. Have any idea about this?